# Select2 - Make each selected option be in its own line

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I was wondering if there's an option in select2 to make each selected item appear in its own line when using multiple selection.

```xml
<select id="items-select" multiple>
  <optgroup label="Items">
     <option>Alpha</option>
     <option>Bravo</option>
     ...
     <option>Zulu</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

```js
$('#items-select').select2();
```

This is the default behavior
[image: default behavior]
I want each option to appear in its own line because the selected options could be 30+ at a time and it would make it easier for the user to check if they got what they wanted.

---

I tried using the `templateSelection` option but adding a line break or a `<br>` tag did nothing there. Currently, I'm able to achieve this by using the following CSS rule

```css
.select2-selection__rendered {
  display: grid !important; /* by default it's inline-block */
}
```

[image: desired behavior]

Is there something I'm missing or is there no other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could add the following CSS rule :

```css
.select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice {
    display: block !important;
    width: fit-content;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It looks a bit prettier now. `display: block` wasn't needed. The default (`display: list-item`) seems to play well with `width: fit-content`